# If there any security risk when public and owner using the same page?

Tags: php, web

They share the most of the functions, however, owner will have edit button. If I just using 
coding to check whether the viewer is a owner and show the edit button to them?

I have many questions on how to implement a web application. I know how to code but I don't 
know what should do, such as calculating the views of a posts (no. of IPs or no. of clicks).
These kinds of question I don't know how to search. Could you please suggest some books or links for me?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have security risk if I correctly understand your question. You should to check user permissions on 'Edit' operations in your backend(PHP). If your code just gives page with link 'Edit' and 'Edit'-page is accessible for all by URL you have a problem with security.

Content for learning:
http://php.net/manual/en/